# Why use infinite energy to change a vacuum to the another in usual SSB?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, higgs, symmetry-breaking

I am reading Strominger's [Lecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05448) in the IR triangle, there is a short argument about differences between the usual Higgs case and Large Gauge Symmetry (LGS) one in P38. Strominger says:

> In the usual story, the different vacua form superselection sectors (i.e., no physical finite energy operator exists that can move us from one vacuum to another). In other words, the charge $Q_\theta$ that would in principle move us between various vacua is not a normalizable operator in the Hilbert space. To see this, consider a system in a vacuum $\rho_0$. Now, suppose we have a bubble with a different value of $\rho$, say $\rho_1$, in the interior. **Then along the surface of this bubble**, $\Phi$ must have a nonzero gradient. Hence the bubble carries energy proportional to its area. To change the vacuum from $\rho_0$ to $\rho_1$ everywhere, we need this bubble to grow in size
> and cover the entire volume of the system.

I can't understand this argument. My main questions are

1. **What is the bubble including vacuums**
2. **Why does moving through the bubble mean changing the vacuum?**

To my knowledge, for the scalar theory $\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu\phi)^2$, the transition probability of one vacuum to the other is running to 0, as the volume creases
\begin{align}
\langle\rho_0|\rho_1\rangle&=\langle\rho_0|e^{iQ_\theta}|\rho_0\rangle\\
&=e^{-cv^2V^{2/3}}\overbrace{\rightarrow}^{V\rightarrow\inf} 0.
\end{align}
where $V$ is the volume of space, and $c$ is a possible constant.
This computational result is seemingly a consequence of Strominger's argument, but I have no idea to connect those two things. So that if possible, please tell me about this connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The argument of Ref. 1 in the scalar theory goes roughly like this:

   - Assume that the bubble profile for the Goldstone field $\rho$ is of the form
     $$\frac{d\rho(r)}{dr}~=~\left\{\begin{array}{ccl} 
     \frac{\rho_0-\rho_1}{\epsilon}&{\rm for}& |r-R|<\epsilon/2 ,\cr
     0 &{\rm for}& |r-R|>\epsilon/2,
     \end{array}\right.$$
     where $R$ is the radius of the bubble, and $\epsilon$ is some small thickness.
   - The Lagrangian can depend on the Goldstone field $\rho$ only via the derivative $\partial_{\mu}\rho$.
   - At the linearized level, the energy in $n$ spatial dimensions is
     $$E~\sim~ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}d^nx~ (\nabla\rho)^2~\sim~ R^{n-1}\frac{(\rho_0-\rho_1)^2}{\epsilon}, $$
     i.e. the bubble fluctuation dies $R\to 0$ (grows $R\to \infty$) for $n>1$ ($n<1$), respectively. This is closely related to the [Mermin-Wagner theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mermin%E2%80%93Wagner_theorem).
   - The Noether charge is $$Q_V~=~\int_Vd^nx~\pi_{\rho}, \qquad \pi_{\rho}~=~\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial\dot{\rho}},$$ in a spatial volume $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. This leads formally to
     $$ e^{i\theta Q_V}|\rho\rangle ~=~ |\rho+ \theta 1_V\rangle, $$
     cf. eq. (2.11.4).
2. In the gauge theory with large gauge transformations, the vacuum configurations live on a codimension-2 submanifold, and hence the effective dimension is shifted by 2 as compared to the scalar theory.

References:

1. A. Strominger, *Lectures on the Infrared Structure of Gravity and Gauge Theory,* [arXiv:1703.05448](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05448); Section 2.11 p. 38.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

I think the bubble is a region of space where the Higgs field has a different value than the surrounding vacuum. The Higgs field is responsible for giving mass to elementary particles, and it can have different possible values or phases. In the usual story, the different vacua form superselection sectors, which means that there is no physical way to go from one vacuum to another. The charge $Q_θ$ that would do that is not a normalizable operator in the Hilbert space, which means that it does not correspond to a well-defined quantum state. To see this, consider a system in a vacuum $ρ_0$ . Now, suppose we have a bubble with a different value of $ρ$ , say $ρ_1$ , in the interior. Then along the surface of this bubble, $Φ$ must have a nonzero gradient. Hence the bubble carries energy proportional to its area. To change the vacuum from $ρ_0$ to $ρ_1$ everywhere, we need this bubble to grow in size and cover the entire volume of the system. This would require an infinite amount of energy, which is impossible. Therefore, the different vacua are physically disconnected.

However, in the case of large gauge symmetry (LGS), there is a way to go from one vacuum to another by using a non-normalizable operator that acts as a symmetry transformation on the boundary of the system. This operator does not conserve energy or charge, but it preserves the gauge invariant observables. This means that there is no physical distinction between the different vacua, and they are all part of the same Hilbert space. The charge $Q_θ$ that would move us between various vacua is now a normalizable operator in the Hilbert space, and it can be created by inserting soft photons or gravitons at infinity. These soft particles carry zero energy and momentum, but they have nonzero angular momentum and helicity. They can change the phase of the Higgs field by an arbitrary amount $θ$ , and thus create a bubble with a different value of $ρ$ . This bubble does not carry any energy or charge, but it has nonzero angular momentum and helicity. It can grow in size without any cost of energy, and eventually cover the entire system.

So, in summary, I think the bubble is a region of space where the Higgs field has a different phase than the surrounding vacuum, and it can be created by either a non-normalizable operator that breaks energy and charge conservation (in LGS case) or by an infinite amount of energy (in usual case).

**Question 2**

Moving through the bubble means changing the vacuum because the bubble has a different value of the Higgs field than the surrounding vacuum. The Higgs field determines the mass of the elementary particles, and thus the properties of the physical vacuum. If the Higgs field changes by an amount $θ$ , then the mass of the particles changes by a factor of $e^θ$ . This means that the physical constants and laws of nature inside and outside the bubble are different. Therefore, moving through the bubble means changing from one vacuum state to another.

**About the connection you did**

I think the connection between Strominger’s argument and your computational result is that they both show that the transition probability between different vacua is suppressed by a factor that depends on the volume of space. In Strominger’s argument, this factor comes from the fact that the charge $Q_θ$ that creates the bubble is non-normalizable, and thus has a vanishing matrix element between different vacua. In your computational result, this factor comes from the overlap integral between different vacua, which is exponentially small for large volume. In both cases, the transition probability goes to zero as the volume goes to infinity, which means that the different vacua are effectively disconnected. However, Strominger’s argument also shows that there is a way to circumvent this suppression by using large gauge symmetry transformations, which can create bubbles with normalizable charges that have nonzero matrix elements between different vacua. This means that the transition probability is not zero, but rather depends on the soft photon or graviton insertions at infinity.